# How do you buy or sell currency using LibOpenMetaverse?

Tags: c#, linden-scripting-language

I am wanting to buy and sell L$ using the LibOpenMetaverse library. LibOpenMetaverse is a C# library that allows you to create programmed avatars for Second Life.

I've looked around at the docs for LibOpenMetaverse and haven't been able to find anything like what I want to do. I'm hoping to be able to buy and sell Lindens, as well as see the current L$ exchange rate.

If there is another way that someone knows of to see the L$ exchange rate, that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could scrape http://moneyslex.com/exchange_rates.php or possibly the liden site itself. I think this would require authentication though.

Comment: Awesome, that URL is exactly what I need. I thought of scraping the Linden site but it does require authentication. Thank you very much!